# Airflow cannot run DAG because of upstream tasks been failed

Tags: python-2.7, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to use Apache Airflow to create a workflow. So basically I've installed Airflow manually in my own anaconda kernel in server.

Here is the way I run a simple DAG

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow/airflow_home # my airflow home
export AIRFLOW=~/.conda/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin
export PATH=~/.conda/.../bin:$AIRFLOW:$PATH # my kernel
```

When I do the same thing using airflow test, it worked for particular task independently. For example, in dag1: task1 >> task2

```
airflow test dag1 task2 2017-06-22
```

I suppose that it will run task1 first then run task2. But it just run task2 independently.

Do you guys have any idea about this ? Thank you very much in advance!

Here is my code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'owner': 'txuantu',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['tran.xuantu@axa.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG(
    'tutorial', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(1))


def python_op1(ds, **kwargs):
    print(ds)
    return 0


def python_op2(ds, **kwargs):
    print(str(kwargs))
    return 0

# t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
# t1 = BashOperator(
#     task_id='bash_operator',
#     bash_command='echo {{ ds }}',
#     dag=dag)
t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='python_operator1',
    python_callable=python_op1,
    # provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)


t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='python_operator2',
    python_callable=python_op2,
    # provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

Airflow: v1.8.0
Using executor SequentialExecutor with SQLLite

```
airflow run tutorial python_operator2 2015-06-01
```

Here is error message:

```
[2017-06-28 22:49:15,336] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/txuantu/airflow/airflow_home/dags
[2017-06-28 22:49:16,069] {base_executor.py:50} INFO - Adding to queue: airflow run tutorial python_operator2 2015-06-01T00:00:00 --mark_success --local -sd DAGS_FOLDER/tutorial.py
[2017-06-28 22:49:16,072] {sequential_executor.py:40} INFO - Executing command: airflow run tutorial python_operator2 2015-06-01T00:00:00 --mark_success --local -sd DAGS_FOLDER/tutorial.py
[2017-06-28 22:49:16,765] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/txuantu/airflow/airflow_home/dags/tutorial.py
[2017-06-28 22:49:16,986] {base_task_runner.py:112} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', u'airflow run tutorial python_operator2 2015-06-01T00:00:00 --mark_success --job_id 1 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/tutorial.py']
[2017-06-28 22:49:17,373] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2017-06-28 22:49:17,373] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2017-06-28 22:49:17,694] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2017-06-28 22:49:17,693] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/txuantu/airflow/airflow_home/dags/tutorial.py
[2017-06-28 22:49:17,899] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2017-06-28 22:49:17,899] {models.py:1120} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: tutorial.python_operator2 2015-06-01 00:00:00 [None]>, dependency 'Trigger Rule' FAILED: Task's trigger rule 'all_success' requires all upstream tasks to have succeeded, but found 1 non-success(es). upstream_tasks_state={'successes': 0, 'failed': 0, 'upstream_failed': 0, 'skipped': 0, 'done': 0}, upstream_task_ids=['python_operator1']
[2017-06-28 22:49:22,011] {jobs.py:2083} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

Comment: Adding description (or code snippet) of task2 might help you to get more answers. This seems to be a problem with path, if your task2 is a BashOperator.

Comment: Thank you for your reponse @Him. Task1 is BashOperator, task2 is PythonOperator. I will add my code for more details. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to run python_operator2, you should execute:

```
airflow run tutorial python_operator2 2015-06-01 --ignore_dependencies=False
```

If you want to execute the entire dag and execute both tasks, use trigger_dag:

```
airflow trigger_dag tutorial
```

For reference, `airflow test` will "run a task without checking for dependencies."

Documentation for all three commands can be found at https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/cli.html

Comment: Thanks Anthony for the reply! Just quick question, how do I check the log of workflow after (airflow trigger_dag tutorial)? I don't see any log in logs/ folder.

Comment: I also checked the sate of trigger_dag: airflow dag_state tutorial 2017-06-28 => result: running. But the state of task: airflow task_state tutorial python_operator2 2017-06-28 => result: None

Comment: Is the first python task actually completing? One possible scenario is that that python_opeartor1 is still running at the time you check and python_operator2 has not kicked off.

Also, not sure about the logs. :(

Comment: I didn't see any result of python_operator1. But I think if it's been kicked of, it will be fast. Also, how about command (airflow run ...)? I ran it but got the error that I mentioned above :(

Comment: So it returns the same error even with the ignore_dependencies flag set to true? Have you tried running your DAG through the GUI? Were you able to find the logs for either of the tasks? It could be possible the op1 is failing and op2 is not kicked off since its a dependency.

Comment: Actually it didn't return anything. I installed in our server without root permission in fact. So the GUI will not work I think

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found about an answer for my problem. Basically I thought airflow is lazy load, but it seems not. So the answer is instead of:

```
t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

It should be:

```
t1.set_downstream(t2)
```